# Tornado + nginx CORS cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, nginx, cors, tornado

I have Tornado app, working as an API server, that processes requests from several other sites. I also plan to use nginx as load balancer.

The problem is CORS cookies. When someone is visiting partner site, `partner.com`, for example, JS script from there sends several requests to my server. The first request is aimed to set several cookies. But it doesnt.

What i have:

1. No header settings on tornado
2. The following config on nginx

   ```
   access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log;

   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://salesmarine.ru;
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
   add_header Set-Cookie test=111;

   location / {
       proxy_pass_header Server;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
       proxy_pass http://api;
       proxy_next_upstream error;
   }
   ```
3. All requests from JS are sent with `.withCredentials=true;` option
   Here are the request data:

   ```
   Accept:*/*
   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
   Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
   Cache-Control:max-age=0
   Connection:keep-alive
   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Cookie:t_id=d9ed7601a2074e78b5ba38ab58ad7043; t_id_session=0c7910f9b3194e899d233e68380df59f;                 test=111
   Host:server.com
   If-None-Match:"bf21a9e8fbc5a3846fb05b4fa0859e0917b2202f"
   Origin:http://example.com
   Referer:http://example.com/test
   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
   Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
   id:54129700102392342dff6dbe
   apiKey:2a8bb0a06bca4ad59c4d4079dce30a30
   client_id:54129700102392342dff6dbe
   apikey:2a8bb0a06bca4ad59c4d4079dce30a30
   user_id:null
   Response Headersview source
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://example.com
   Connection:keep-alive
   Date:Fri, 12 Sep 2014 19:40:17 GMT
   Etag:"bf21a9e8fbc5a3846fb05b4fa0859e0917b2202f"
   Mime-Type:text/javascript
   Server:TornadoServer/4.0.2
   Set-Cookie:test=111
   ```

And no cookies are sent. What could be the problem?

And also what is better — control headers from tornado, or nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've figured it out. The problem was CORS itself — i'm unable to set cookies for another domain.
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` allow to do this, but that cookies would be unavailable for JS on that domain.

There are plenty of links to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) resourse, but it's really useful for understanding CORS.

The second part of my initial question is stay ambiguous to me. A wild guess — if you use nginx + tornado, nginx receives incoming requests first. So it should return proper headers.